# Find next smallest number that's representable as a sum of distinct powers of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm solving this [challenge](https://www.prepbytes.com/panel/mycourses/125-days-expert-coder-program/python/week/1/logic-building/codingAssignment/DISNUM):

> Given a positive integer number, you have to find the smallest *good* number greater than or equal to the given number.
> The positive integer is called *good* if it can be represented as a sum of distinct powers of 3 (i.e. no duplicates of powers of 3 are allowed).

The code passes all the test cases in the editor, but when submitted to online judge it is failing because of time limit exceeded.
Give time limit 1 second, my code execution is taking 1.01 second

---

```
t = int(input())
while t > 0:
    N = int(input())
    i=N
    while i > 0:
        if i % 3 == 2:
            N=N+1
            i=N
            continue
        i //= 3
    print(N)
    t = t - 1
```

---

#### Test Case

Input:

```
5
3
46
65
89
113
```

Output:

```
3
81
81
90
117
```

Comment: Your test case output is missing the output from $5$.  It should be $9$, I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach would be to use ternary numbers, at least at development. Number that's representable as a sum of power of 3 in ternary would consist of 0's and 1's only. So:

repeat:

- convert the number to ternary;
- if there's no 2's in it - return it;
- if there're 2's - find the leftmost 2, change all digits starting with it into 0 and add 1 to the next digit to the left.

I think it can be done in one pass of conversion into ternary.

Update: here's my code, it's \$O(log(n))\$ (yours is \$O(nlog(n))\$):

```
def find_distinct_pow3(number):
    result = 0 
    power = 1
    while number:
        number, digit = divmod(number, 3)
        if digit<2:
            result += power*digit #just copying the digit into the result
        else:
            result = 0 #discarding current result (after the digit 2)
            number += 1 #increasing the digit before 2
        power *= 3
    return result
```

Comment: execution time 0.02 sec,thanks